# Why is java giving "Unclosed Group" error for this regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to implement this regex to validate emails:

`([-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+(\.[-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+)*|"([]!#-[^-~ \t]|(\\[\t -~]))+")@([-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+(\.[-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+)*|\[[\t -Z^-~]*])`

So I added an extra `\` to escape the existing `\` in the regex and also escaped the `"` and ended up with this:

`([-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+(\\.[-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+)*|\"([]!#-[^-~ \\t]|(\\\\[\\t -~]))+\")@([-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+(\\.[-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+)*|\\[[\\t -Z^-~]*])`

Now I'm getting error:

`Unclosed group near index 145`

Any ideas?

Comment: @Dici  I have 6 sets of parentheses and 9 sets of brackets.  I don't see what needs closing.

Comment: Then remove the sub-groups one by one, or count the brackets, or write a code counting the brackets, or use your text editor to match the openning brackets with their close bracket. Whatever, but I don't think SO is a place to debug a 2 lines long regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to escape two chars: '[' and ']'. Try this instead:

```
"([-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+(\\.[-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+)*|\"(\\[\\]!#-[^-~ \\t]|(\\\\[\\t -~]))+\")@([-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+(\\.[-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+)*|\\[[\\t -Z^-~]*])"
```